# How to switch between 2 function sets in C++?

Tags: c++, c, function, performance

Is there a way, I can switch between 2 similar function sets (C/C++) in an effective way?
To explain better what I mean, lets say I have 2 sets of global functions like:

```
void a_someCoolFunction();
void a_anotherCoolFunction(int withParameters);
…

void b_someCoolFunction();
void b_anotherCoolFunction(int withParameters);
…
```

And I want to able to "switch" in my program at runtime which one is used. BUT: I dont want to have one if condition at *every* function, like:

```
void inline someCoolFunction(){
    if(someState = A_STATE){
        a_someCoolFunction();
    }else{
        b_someCoolFunction();
    }
}
```

Because, I expect that every function is called a lot in my mainloop - so It would be preferable if I could do something like this (at start of my mainloop or when someState is changed):

```
if(someState = A_STATE){
    useFunctionsOfType = a;
}else{
    useFunctionsOfType = b;
}
```

and then simply call

```
useFunctionsOfType _someCoolFunction();
```

I hope its understandable what I mean…  My Background: Im writing an App, that should be able to handle OpenGL ES 1.1 and OpenGL ES 2.0 both properly - but I dont want to write every render Method 2 times (like: `renderOpenGL1()` and `renderOpenGL2()` I would rather to write only `render()`). I already have similiar Methods like: `glLoadIdentity(); myLoadIdentity();` … But need a way to switch between these two somehow.
Is there any way to accomplish this in an efficent way?

Comment: Sounds like function pointers should do the trick.

Comment: Note: please don't conflate C and C++ like this.  The potential solutions are very different depending on which language you're working with.  Please pick one!

Comment: If every function is called `alot`, then you just have to modify the dispatcher inside `alot()`. By the way, this `alot` must be quite a hairy beast! http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html

Comment: `if(someState = A_STATE)` should probably be `if(someState == A_STATE)`. Just saying.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: I'm using principally C++, but mentioned also C because I thought there's maybe an more efficient C-style solution out there. Wasn't aware, that's proscribed to mix them - Sorry.

Comment: @Constantin: it's not proscribed, but a C++ solution could be difficult to implement in C...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C (since it seems you want both C and C++) this is done with pointer to functions.

```
// Globals. Default to the a_ functions
void(*theCoolFunction)()           = a_someCoolFunction;
void(*theOtherCoolFunction)(int)   = a_anotherCoolFunction;

// In the code ...
{
  ...
  // use the other functions 
  theCoolFunction = b_someCoolFunction;
  theOtherCoolFunction = b_anotherCoolFunction;
  ...
}
```

You might probably want to switch those functions in groups, so you better set a array of pointers to functions and pass that array around.  If you decide to do so, you might probably want to also define some macro to ease the reading:

```
   void (*functions_a[2])();
   void (*functions_b[2])();

   void (**functions)() = functions_a;

   ....
   #define theCoolFunction()       functions[0]()
   #define theOtherCoolFunction(x) functions[1](x) 
   ....

    // switch grooup:
   functions = functions_b;
```

but in this case you'll lose the static check on argument types (and you have to initialize the array, of course).

I guess in C++ you will have instatiate two different objects with the same parent class and different implementation for their methods (but I'm no C++ prograammer!)

Answer (score 7):

Several options, including (but not limited to):

- Use function pointers.
- Wrap them in classes, and use polymorphism.
- Have two separate copies of the loop.

But please *profile* to ensure this is *actually* a problem, *before* you make any large changes to your code.

Answer (score 4):

As the question seems to be interested in a C++ solution and no-one has spelt out the polymorphic solution (too obvious?), here goes.

Define an abstract base class with the API you require, and then implement a derived class for each supported implementation:

```
class OpenGLAbstract
{
   public:
       virtual ~OpenGLAbstract() {}
       virtual void loadIdentity() = 0;
       virtual void someFunction() = 0;
};

class OpenGLEs11 : public OpenGLAbstract
{
   public:
       virtual void loadIdentity()  
       {
           // Call 1.1 API

       }
       virtual void someFunction() 
       {
           // Call 1.1 API
       }
};


class OpenGLEs20 : public OpenGLAbstract
{
   public:
       virtual void loadIdentity()  
       {
           // Call 2.0 API
       }
       virtual void someFunction() 
       {
           // Call 2.0 API
       }
};

int main()
{
    // Select the API to use:
    bool want11 = true;
    OpenGLAbstract* gl = 0;
    if (want11)
        gl = new OpenGLEs11;
    else
        gl = new OpenGLEs20;

    // In the main loop.
    gl->loadIdentity();

    delete gl;
}
```

Note that this is exactly the sort of thing that C++ was intended for, so if can use C++ here, this is the simplest way to go.

Now a more subtle issue you might face is if your 2.0 version requires the process to load a dynamic linked library at run time with the 2.0 platform implementation. In that case just supporting the API switch is not enough (whatever the solution). Instead put each OpenGL concrete class in its own linked library and in each provide a factory function to create that class:

```
OpenGlAbstract* create();
```

Then load the desired library at run time and call the create() method to access the API.

Comment: +1, I was beginning to wonder if people would stay at the pointer to function and array of pointers to function for long...

Answer (score 2):

You could use functions pointers. You can read a lot about them if you google it, but briefly a function pointer stores a pointer to a function's memory address.

Function pointers can be used the same way as a funcion, but can be assigned the address of different functions, making it a somehow "dynamic" function. As an example:

```
typedef int (*func_t)(int);


int divide(int x) {
    return x / 2;
}

int multiply(int x) {
    return x * 2;
}

int main() {
    func_t f = &divide;
    f(2); //returns 1
    f = &multiply;
    f(2); //returns 4
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like boost::function (std::function) would fit the bill.  Using your example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/function.hpp> //requires boost installation
#include <functional> //c++0x header


void a_coolFunction() {

    std::cout << "Calling a_coolFunction()" << std::endl;
}

void a_coolFunction(int param) {

     std::cout << "Calling a_coolFunction(" << param << ")" << std::endl;
}

void b_coolFunction() {

    std::cout << "Calling b_coolFunction()" << std::endl;
}

void b_coolFunction(int param) {

    std::cout << "Calling b_coolFunction(" << param << ")" << std::endl;
}
float mul_ints(int x, int y) {return ((float)x)*y;}


int main() {

    std::function<void()> f1;  //included in c++0x 
    boost::function<void(int)> f2; //boost, works with current c++
    boost::function<float(int,int)> f3;

    //casts are necessary to resolve overloaded functions
    //otherwise you don't need them
   f1 = static_cast<void(*)()>(a_coolFunction);
   f2 = static_cast<void(*)(int)>(a_coolFunction);

   f1();
   f2(5);

   //switching
   f1 = static_cast<void(*)()>(b_coolFunction);
   f2 = static_cast<void(*)(int)>(b_coolFunction);

   f1();
   f2(7);

   //example from boost::function documentation.  No cast required.
   f3 = mul_ints;
   std::cout << f3(5,3) << std::endl;

}
```

Compiled with g++-4.4.4, this outputs:

```
Calling a_coolFunction()
Calling a_coolFunction(5)
Calling b_coolFunction()
Calling b_coolFunction(7)
15
```

The biggest limitation is that the types of f1,f2, etc cannot change, so any function you assign to them must have the same signature (i.e. void(int) in the case of f2).

Answer (score 1):

The simple way could be storing pointers to functions, and change them od demand.

But the better way is to use something similar to [abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory)  design pattern. The nice generic implementation can be found in [Loki library](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/index.php?n=Pattern.AbstractFactory).

Answer (score 1):

In C you would typically do this with a `struct` containing function pointers:

```
struct functiontable {
    void (*someCoolFunction)(void);
    void (*anotherCoolFunction)(int);
};

const struct functiontable table_a = { &a_someCoolFunction, &a_anotherCoolFunction };
const struct functiontable table_b = { &b_someCoolFunction, &b_anotherCoolFunction };

const struct functiontable *ftable = NULL;
```

To switch the active function table, you'd use:

```
ftable = &table_a;
```

To call the functions, you'd use:

```
ftable->someCoolFunction();
```